# How do I implement a checkbox list in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am looking to implement a checkboxlist in ASP.NET Core, but am facing some difficulties.

My ViewModel:

```
public class GroupIndexViewModel
{
    public Filter[] Filters { get; set; }
}

public class Filter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

My View:

```
@model GroupIndexViewModel
<form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Group" method="get">
  <ul>
  @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Filters.Length; i++)
  {
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="@Model.Filters[i].Name" asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].Selected" value="@Model.Filters[i].Selected" checked="@Model.Filters[i].Selected" />
      <label for="@Model.Filters[i].Name">@Model.Filters[i].Name</label>
    </li>
  }
  </ul>
  <button type="submit" name="action">Filtrer</button>
</form>
```

When posting to my controller, the Filter property in my viewmodel shows selected false even though it is selected in the view.

Comment: Have you tried using `Html.CheckboxFor( m => m.Filters[i].Name )` instead?

Comment: Also, what does the rendered HTML look like with your existing Razor code?

Comment: if for the checkbox input field in addition to the asp-for property you specify the checked and/or value property, then the actual checkbox state will not be passed correctly to the POST action. If you leave it out with just asp-for then it will work.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I would do following way.

```
@model GroupIndexViewModel
<form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Group" method="get">
    <ul>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Filters.Count; i++)
        {
            <li>       
                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].Selected"  />
                <label asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].Selected">@Model.Filters[i].Name</label>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].Id" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].Name" />                
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    <button type="submit" name="action">Filtrer</button>
</form>
```

Here I assuming that you have proper implementation of controller and action.

Comment: If you look at Filter class it has three property Id, Name and Selected. Name is use for Display against checkbox. Otherwise nothing will display for checkbox. We can do without label as well directly print @Model.Filters[i].Name but as question has that label I have used that as I don't see any problem in that.

Comment: The key thing here is asp-for adds to the passed back ViewModel only from <input> tags. That is why we need the hidden ones that store Model..Name, which is also unrelatedly used to give the <label> text. This took me a while to figure out and it was rather frustrating...

Comment: another key note - you must use "for" not "foreach" so the viewmodel can pickup on the property name (in this case - "Filter")

Answer (score 28):

#### The question might be already answered but I wanted to explain your issue, so others can understand what's happening.

You are not aware that you are already specifying the `false` value to your input, since you're implementing a bad use of attributes.

**Let's take a look at your view**

```
@model GroupIndexViewModel
<form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Group" method="get">
   <ul>
     @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Filters.Length; i++)
     {
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="@Model.Filters[i].Name" asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].Selected" value="@Model.Filters[i].Selected" checked="@Model.Filters[i].Selected" />
        <label for="@Model.Filters[i].Name">@Model.Filters[i].Name</label>
     </li>
     }
  </ul>
  <button type="submit" name="action">Filtrer</button>
</form>
```

So, first. You are creating input elements from an array of `Filter`. Now let's take a closer look at your input element.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="@Model.Filters[i].Name" asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].Selected" value="@Model.Filters[i].Selected" checked="@Model.Filters[i].Selected" />
```

Now, let me explain this.

1. You are specifying a type, using the `type` attribute.
2. You are specifying an id, using the `id` attribute.
3. You bind the input to the model, using the `asp-for` tag helper.
4. You specify a value for the input, using the `value` attribute.
5. Finally, you set the input as checked, with the `checked` attribute.

If you take a look at the [Tag Helpers Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms#the-input-tag-helper), you'll find the relationship between the **.Net Type** and the **Input Type**, understanding that:

> Checkboxes holds a **boolean** value, corresponding to the model, and formatted by the tag helper as `type="checkbox"`.

Since you're using the `type="checkbox"` attribute, the Tag Helper value can only be `true` or `false`. So, if we go back and look at the input element, you're already specifying a value to the input. Even though the tag-helper can assign a value to the input, it can't override the one already specified. Therefore, your input, will always have the value you've specified, in this case, a `boolean` is **always [false by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table)**.

Now you might think that your input element, has a `false` value, and for instance, adding the `checked="checked"` **will not** change the value to `true`, since the `value` attributes, overrides the `checked` attribute. Causing a bad implementation of both attributes.

Therefore, you must use **only one** of the attributes. (Either the `value` or the `checked`). You can use them, for convenience. But in this case, you **must** use the default `checked` attribute. Since you're implementing a Tag Helper, and the input value, have to be of type `boolean`. And the `checked` attribute value, [returns a boolean](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp) and for instance, is the one used by the Tag Helper.

So the implementation provided by [@dotnetstep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385326/dotnetstep) should work, since it only declares the tag helper in the input element. So the Tag Helper, handles itself the corresponding attributes of the input.

```
@model GroupIndexViewModel
<form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Group" method="get">
    <ul>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Filters.Count; i++)
        {
            <li>       
                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].Selected"  />
                <label asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].Selected">@Model.Filters[i].Name</label>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].Id" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].Name" />                
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    <button type="submit" name="action">Filtrer</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 11):

Building on @dotnetstep's answer, I created a Tag Helper that takes a model of **IEnumerable of SelectListItem** and generates the fields described in his answer.

Here is the Tag Helper code:

```
[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "asp-checklistbox, asp-modelname")]
public class CheckListBoxTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-checklistbox")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-modelname")]
    public string ModelName { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            var selected = item.Selected ? @"checked=""checked""" : "";
            var disabled = item.Disabled ? @"disabled=""disabled""" : "";

            var html = $@"<label><input type=""checkbox"" {selected} {disabled} id=""{ModelName}_{i}__Selected"" name=""{ModelName}[{i}].Selected"" value=""true"" /> {item.Text}</label>";
            html += $@"<input type=""hidden"" id=""{ModelName}_{i}__Value"" name=""{ModelName}[{i}].Value"" value=""{item.Value}"">";
            html += $@"<input type=""hidden"" id=""{ModelName}_{i}__Text"" name=""{ModelName}[{i}].Text"" value=""{item.Text}"">";

            output.Content.AppendHtml(html);

            i++;
        }

        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", "th-chklstbx");
    }
}
```

You will need to add the following to the _ViewImports.cshtml file:

```
@addTagHelper *, <ProjectName>
```

Then to drop the check list box into your razor view it's as easy as:

```
<div asp-checklistbox="Model.Brands" asp-modelname="Brands"></div>
```

You might notice that I'm adding a class attribute to the div to style the box and it's content. Here is the CSS:

```
.th-chklstbx {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px ;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px ;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px ;
  border-radius: 5px ; 
}
.th-chklstbx label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: This is great. Not sure on .Net Core 1 but on .Net Core 2 don't forget to add this to your __ViewImports.cshtml file: @addTagHelper *, <ProjectNamespace>

Comment: Thanks for the additional info agileMike! I forgot to include that requirement. I've added that to my response.

Comment: what is Model.Brands ?

Answer (score 4):

Standing on the shoulders of @dotnetstep and @gsxrboy73, this approach adds an optional control title and "Check All" type of checkbox.  It also serializes "id" attributes so you can safely have multiple Check Box Lists on a page.  This is tailored for .NET 5 binding to MVC Models in a Bootstrap environment.

I prefer thin and light models that don't rope in giant mvc libraries:

```
public class CheckBoxListItem
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; } = false;
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; } = false;
}
```

A `List<CheckBoxListItem>` drives the Tag Helper:

```
/// <summary>check-box-list Tag Helper</summary>
[HtmlTargetElement("Check-Box-List", Attributes = "asp-title, asp-items, asp-model-name, asp-check-all-label", TagStructure=TagStructure.NormalOrSelfClosing)]
public class CheckBoxListTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    /// <summary>HTML element ID of the tracking form element</summary>
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-form-id")]
    public string FormId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Optional bolder title set above the check box list</summary>
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-title")]
    public string ListTitle { get; set; }

    /// <summary>List of individual child/item values to be rendered as check boxes</summary>
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-items")]
    public List<CheckBoxListItem> Items { get; set; }

    /// <summary>The name of the view model which is used for rendering html "id" and "name" attributes of each check box input.
    /// Typically the name of a List[CheckBoxListItem] property on the actual passed in @Model</summary>
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-model-name")]
    public string ModelName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Optional label of a "Check All" type checkbox.  If left empty, a "Check All" check box will not be rendered.</summary>
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-check-all-label")]
    public string CheckAllLabel { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        string id = context.UniqueId;
        output.TagName = "div";
        string html = "";

        output.PreElement.AppendHtml($"<!-- Check List Box for {(string.IsNullOrEmpty(ListTitle) ? ModelName : ListTitle)} -->\r\n");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ListTitle))
        {
            // Prepend a Title to the control
            output.PreContent.AppendHtml($"\r\n\t<label id=\"check-box-list-label-{id}\" class=\"cblTitle\">\r\n"
                + $"\t\t<strong>{ListTitle}</strong>\r\n"
                + $"\t</label>\r\n");
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CheckAllLabel))
        {
            // Prepend a "Check All" type checkbox to the control
            output.PreContent.AppendHtml("\t<div class=\"form-check\">\r\n"
                + $"\t\t<input id=\"check-box-list-all-{id}\"\r\n"
                + "\t\t\tclass=\"cblCheckAllInput form-check-input\"\r\n"
                + "\t\t\ttype=\"checkbox\"\r\n"
                + $"\t\t\tvalue=\"true\"\r\n"
                );

            if (Items.All(cbli => cbli.IsChecked))
            {
                output.PreContent.AppendHtml("\t\t\tchecked=\"checked\"\r\n");
            }

            output.PreContent.AppendHtml("\t\t\t/>\r\n"
                + $"\t\t<label id=\"check-box-list-all-label-{id}\" class=\"cblCheckAllLabel form-check-label\" for=\"check-box-list-all-{id}\">\r\n"
                + $"\t\t\t&nbsp; {CheckAllLabel}\r\n"
                + "\t\t</label>\r\n"
                + "\t</div>\r\n"
                ) ;
        }

        // Begin the actual Check Box List control
        output.Content.AppendHtml($"\t<div id=\"cblContent-{id}\" class=\"cblContent\">\r\n");

        // Create an individual check box for each item
        for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count(); i++)
        {
            CheckBoxListItem item = Items[i];
            html = "\t\t<div class=\"form-check\">\r\n"
                + $"\t\t\t<input id=\"{ModelName}_{i}__IsChecked-{id}\"\r\n"
                + $"\t\t\t\tname=\"{ModelName}[{i}].IsChecked\"\r\n"
                + $"\t\t\t\tclass=\"cblCheckBox form-check-input\"\r\n"
                + $"\t\t\t\tform=\"{FormId}\"\r\n"
                + "\t\t\t\tdata-val=\"true\"\r\n"
                + "\t\t\t\ttype=\"checkbox\""
                + "\t\t\t\tvalue=\"true\""
                ;

            if (item.IsChecked)
            {
                html += "\t\t\t\tchecked=\"checked\"\r\n";
            }

            if (item.IsDisabled)
            {
                html += "\t\t\t\tdisabled=\"disabled\"\r\n";
            }

            html += "\t\t\t\t/>\r\n"
                + $"\t\t\t<label id=\"check-box-list-item-label-{id}-{i}\" class=\"cblItemLabel form-check-label\" for=\"{ModelName}_{i}__IsChecked-{id}\">\r\n"
                + $"\t\t\t\t&nbsp; {item.Value}\r\n"
                + "\t\t\t</label>\r\n"
                + $"\t\t\t<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"{ModelName}_{i}__IsChecked-{id}-tag\" name=\"{ModelName}[{i}].IsChecked\" form =\"{FormId}\" value=\"false\">\r\n"
                + $"\t\t\t<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"{ModelName}_{i}__Key-{id}\" name=\"{ModelName}[{i}].Key\" form =\"{FormId}\" value=\"{item.Key}\">\r\n"
                + $"\t\t\t<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"{ModelName}_{i}__Value-{id}\" name=\"{ModelName}[{i}].Value\" form =\"{FormId}\" value=\"{item.Value}\">\r\n"
                + "\t\t</div>\r\n"
                ;

            output.Content.AppendHtml(html);
        }

        output.Content.AppendHtml("\t</div>\r\n");
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("id", $"check-box-list-{id}");
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", "cblCheckBoxList");
    }
}
```

Revealing prototype JS makes the "Check All" box play nice with the others:

```
// Attach event handlers to controls
$(function () {

    // Toggle child check boxes per the "Check All" check box state
    $("div.cblCheckBoxList").on("click", "input.cblCheckAllInput", function (event) {

        let chkBoxListDiv = $(event.target).closest("div.cblCheckBoxList");
        let chkBoxList = new checkBoxList($(chkBoxListDiv).attr("id"), $(event.target).attr("id"));

        chkBoxList.onCheckAllClick();
    });

    // Sync the "Check All" box w/ the child check boxes' check box states
    $("div.cblCheckBoxList").on("click", "input.cblCheckBox", function (event) {

        let chkBoxListDiv = $(event.target).closest("div.cblCheckBoxList");
        let chkBoxList = new checkBoxList($(chkBoxListDiv).attr("id"), null);

        chkBoxList.onCheckItemClick();
    });
});


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  Check Box List
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var checkBoxList = function (checkBoxListDivId, checkAllInputId) {

    this.listDivId = checkBoxListDivId;
    this.allInputId = (checkAllInputId ?? $("#" + this.listDivId).find("input.cblCheckAllInput")?.first()?.attr("id"));
};

checkBoxList.prototype = function () {

    // If a "Check All" type check box is clicked, update the individual child check boxes accordingly
    var onCheckAllClick = function () {

        // Find the "Check All" check box that was clicked
        let checkAllInput = $('#' + this.allInputId);

        // Determine whether the "Check All" check box is checked or unchecked
        let chkd = $(checkAllInput).prop('checked');

        // Get a list of child/item check boxes
        let chks = $('#' + this.listDivId).find('input.cblCheckBox');

        // Make the child/item check boxes match the value of the "Check All" check box
        chks.prop('checked', chkd);
    },

    // If an individual child check box is clicked and a "Check All" type checkbox exists, update it accordingly
    onCheckItemClick = function () {

        if (!((this.allInputId === undefined) || (this.allInputId.length === 0))) {

            // Get an array of check boxes that are NOT checked
            let notChkd = $('#' + this.listDivId).find("input.cblCheckBox:not(:checked)");

            // Update the "Check All" check box accordingly
            $("#" + this.allInputId).prop('checked', (notChkd.length === 0));
        }
    };

    return {
        onCheckAllClick: onCheckAllClick,
        onCheckItemClick: onCheckItemClick
    };
}();
```

Slap some CSS lipstick on:

```
/*  For CheckBoxList form control   */
.cblCheckBoxList {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
    .cblCheckBoxList .cblContent {
        height: 150px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .cblCheckBoxList .cblTitle {
        font-weight: bolder;
    }

    .cblCheckBoxList .cblCheckAllLabel {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .cblCheckBoxList .cblCheckAllInput {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .cblCheckBoxList .cblItemLabel {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: small;
    }

    .cblCheckBoxList .cblCheckBox {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: small;
    }
```

And drop the Check Box List onto a page:

```
@* On the passed in View Model, "IceCreamFlavors" is a property that is a List of type CheckBoxListItem *@
<check-box-list 
    asp-title="Ice Cream Flavors"
    asp-items="Model.IceCreamFlavors"
    asp-model-name="IceCreamFlavors"
    asp-form-id="my-form-id"
    asp-check-all-label="All Flavors"
    >
</check-box-list>
```

Botta boom, botta bing.

Comment: In one of the oddest quirks I've encountered, no matter what I did, the first checkbox in the list would NEVER convey a checked status to the controller action when it bound submitted data to the action's view model parameter.  The only fix I found was to add the `form="my-form-id`' attribute to the rendered checkbox inputs.

Comment: It doesn't post back to a model in a post action. How did you get this to work?

Answer (score -3):

I just tried this and it worked:

```
<input asp-for="filter.type[i].IsEnabled"/>
```

without the checkbox, and then corresponding boolean value in model with hidden id and name.