# CheckBox Multiple Selector Asp.net.core RazorPages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, checkbox, razor-pages

I'm working in entityframework 6.
I have a problem with my Checkbox. I'm trying to select multiple of choices then save these choices to a List, save them to my `PostModel` which holds an `ICollection<TagLogs>`.
Like any other i scoured the net for a solution, and followed some, but to no answer.
I am getting this error:
***InvalidOperationException: Unexpected 'asp-for' expression result type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]' for . 'asp-for' must be of type 'System.Boolean' or 'System.String' that can be parsed as a 'System.Boolean' if 'type' is 'checkbox'.*** I understand i need to change the SelectedChanges and make it to a Boolean or a string, then change few other things, but i still got more errors.

```
    [BindProperty]
    public List<int> SelectedChanges { get; set; } = new List<int>();
    public IEnumerable<TagLog> TagLogs { get; set; }

      public async Task OnGet()
     {
        //ChangeLogs = changeLogRepository.GetAllModels();
        TagLogs = await context.TagLogs.ToListAsync();
        //SelectedChanges = new List<int>();
    }  


    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newPost = context.PostModels.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Title == PostViewModel.Title);
            if (newPost == null)
            {
             

                if (TagLogs != null)
                {
                    var selectedType = TagLogs.Where(x => SelectedChanges.Contains(x.TagLogId)).ToList();
               

                    PostModel postModel = new PostModel
                    {
                        Title = PostViewModel.Title,
                    
                        ChangeLogs = selectedType,
               
                    };
                 
               
                }
               
                    postRepository.Add(postModel);

                    TagLogs = changeLogRepository.GetAllModels();
                }

                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }
            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
        }
        FailedToPost = "Failed to Post, try again.";
        return Page();
    }
 public class TagLog
  {
    [Key]
    public int TagLogId { get; set; }
    public string TagLogName { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostModel>? PostModels { get; set; }
   }
```

Front End

```
       @foreach (var change in Model.TagLogs)
                {
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <!-- Set the value of the input to the change ID -->
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="SelectedChanges" value="@change.TagLogId" />
                        <label class="form-check-label">@change.TagLogName</label>
                    </div>
                }
                </div>
```

Best regards.

Comment: You cannot use `asp-for` for Lists. You have to use a boolean or a string property. There is a way to populate a list of checkboxes. But you need to create a separate viewmodel or a additional property in your existing models. Please see this post for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40555543/how-do-i-implement-a-checkbox-list-in-asp-net-core

Comment: From my understanding, is that i'm using the asp-for wrong, and i should change my 
IEnumreble to Something else.

Comment: you can add a Property `Checked` (if it is entity model you can add attribute `NotMapped`) on the model `TagLog` and in your frontend you have to use for loop and then you can use `asp-for="change[i].Checked"`

Comment: I'm unsure what your referring to, Never used the "Checked property, so i'm not fully on what that would look like, but i'll search for it.   "'asp-for="change[i].Checked' " Could you clarify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Help of a little ChatGPT and some skills of my own i managed to fix it. Ofcourse tons of stackoverflows. I hope my answer will help others.
Also want to thank @Sebastian Siemens for pointing out things.
What i was missing was loading the Taglogs before i compared where SelectedTaglos and SelectedChanged contained same id. Now this might be some bad and rookie mistake, but it took more time than i would like to admit.

```
          <div class="form-group">
                <h4>Select Multiple Logs</h4>
                @foreach (var change in Model._tagLogs)
                {
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="SelectedChanges" value="@change.TagId"
                           @(Model.SelectedChanges.Contains(change.TagId) ? "checked" : "") />
                        <label class="form-check-label">@change.TagTyp</label>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>

       public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newPost = context.PostModels.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Title == PostViewModel.Title);
            if (newPost == null)
            {
                _tagLogs = await context._TagLogs.ToListAsync();
                // takes multiple checkbox values
                var selectedTagLogs = _tagLogs.Where(x => SelectedChanges.Contains(x.TagId)).ToList();
                if (selectedTagLogs != null)
                {


                    PostModel postModel = new PostModel
                    {
                        Title = PostViewModel.Title,

                        _TagLogs = selectedTagLogs,

                    };
                    postRepository.Add(postModel);

                    _tagLogs = changeLogRepository.GetAllModels();
                }
            
                

                    _tagLogs = changeLogRepository.GetAllModels();
                }

      
            }
        }

        return Page();
    }
```